# Program type already present: android.support.v4.util.TimeUtils

Tags: java, android

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: '*.jar', dir: 'libs')
    implementation files('libs/achartengine-1.0.0.jar')
    implementation files('libs/commons-lang3-3.4/commons-lang3-3.4.jar')
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0-beta4'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
//        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

        // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
        // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
        // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
        // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
        // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
        // by a similar customization.
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "br.com.ledtec.app"
        minSdkVersion 9
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

repositories {
    google()
}
```

Qual seria a solução para o erro título do código?